How can I create a VM in virt-manager that can access the internet through the host but can't even see the host or other devices on the LAN?
I want to create a VM for testing purposes -- questionable websites, files that could be infected with a virus, etc.
So I want to create a VM and that VM should be able to access the internet but it should not be able to access the host or any other device on the LAN.
I tried NAT mode but that let's me access the host and other devices on the LAN.
I tried Isolated mode but that doesn't give me internet access.
What do I need to do?

You can still use the NAT mode, but modify some iptables rules on the host.

On the host open virt-manager, and set up a virtual network using NAT mode. Notice the IP address range and device name it's using, e.g. 192.168.100.0/24 on virbr1.

Open a shell command prompt. Delete the rule which forwards all traffic out of that specific virtual bridge device:
sudo iptables -D LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.100.0/24 -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT

Insert a new rule, which only forwards non-local traffic, to the front of the chain of the chain LIBVIRT_FWO:
sudo iptables -I LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.x.0/24 -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT
where the 192.168.x.0/24 is your local network segment.

Insert a new rule, which rejects traffic directed to the host, to the front of the chain LIBVIRT_INP:
sudo iptables -I LIBVIRT_INP -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 192.168.x.y -i virbr1 -j REJECT

Use the virtual network interface created at step 1 for your VM.


This should give your VM a connection to the Internet but not to your local network. I don't know whether this setup is secure. Please make sure it meets your security requirements yourself.
